# Can I restrict rights to an API user in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

The devs working with me are asking if we can give only Read access to some developpers, and full access to others ?

I know only, in Setup, the Apps> Installed Package > Instance API values. But It's for the whole API access here.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You would create different installed packages for different access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @EazyE noted, you would need to create different API Applications.  There are no user controls beyond that.

Comment: Thank you both , I didn't know it was possible :) That's very clear !

Comment: Hi again, can't we limit more than with a Read/Write/Send status? Like being able to delete only the content created by this access ? Or being able to send only transactional emails but no commercial emails ? Or being able to send Emails only to Tests Data Extensions in a first time, then later being able to send to all DE ?